# Routing and cache issues in angular, route path contains empty string

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am working on routing in angular and I am facing issues in couple of things:

1)  In my `app.component.ts` which is the 1st component file which gets called, I have the following function:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
ngOnInit() {
        if(this.authService.isUserAuthenticated()){

            this.router.navigate([this.route]);
        }
    }
```

So, here I am checking if the user is already logged in, I am redirecting to the current route. So, if I have a route like `http://localhost:4200/user/messages/5b43add9111d0c5e00430d08` , and user does a refresh of the page, it successfully routes him to the correct route. But when I add a breakpoint and check the value of `this.route`, I see the path as empty( `path=""`). If the path is empty, how is the routing working fine. I need to have a condition based routing over here, and since path is empty, I am not able to apply the conditions.

2) Another issue which I am facing is with the Authorization token. I save the token in localstorage and use it for my api calls. However, when the user clears the cache, the token gets removed and my applications fails. Is there some kind of listener I can use to check the moment localstorage is cleared, I call my logout api?

**Edit**
In the 1st case, although the routing is happening in-spite of path being empty, I just checked the console and I am getting the following errors:

```
 Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at createNewSegmentGroup (router.js:2531)
```

and

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '5b43add9111d0c5e00430d08'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '5b43add9111d0c5e00430d08'
```

How is page routed correctly if I am getting these errors?

Comment: IMO, you don't have to log user out at once. When user's behavior calls a service, you can catch a 401 response as no auth header is set to request. Then you can redirect to login page. If user navigates to another page, you can just set an `AuthGuardService` to router's `canActivate`.

Comment: Hi, can someone answer the 1st part of the question, I am still stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

For conditional Routing you could do:  Basically check for route.routeConfig.path instead of route

```
switch (route.routeConfig.path) {
    case "your route configured path" :
    // Ex: "admin", "reports"
        this.router.navigate([this.route]);
}
```

for #2
You should implement Route Activation.
Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthActivateGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authEventService: AuthEventService, private router: Router, private userRoleHelper: UserRoleHelper) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        if (window.location.hash) {
            console.log('redirect sign in');
            this.authEventService.redirectCallback();
        }

        return this.authEventService.getUser().map(user => {
            if (user !== undefined && user !== null) {
... // Route since the user is active.
}
```

and in the routes define a route

```
{ path: 'reporting', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [AuthActivateGuard]  },
```

Comment: route.routeConfig is coming out to be null in my case.